# Shared data format between iOS and Mac OS

Tags: ios, macos

This is mainly a question about architecture and I do apologize if it's inappropriate for SO. I'm building a Mac OS application that is meant for creating content and the iOS application is meant for consuming the content. I am unsure about what data format to use and if I need to convert it to binary format. I know I can use iTunes to share files but I am wondering if anyone has done anything similar?

Comment: Is your OS X app document based?

Comment: Should it be? Essentially, I want to be able to create some form of a document on my Mac application and then transfer it over to the iOS application to open it. I'm not sure if iOS has functionality for NSDocument?

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever format you want: iTunes simply copies files and directories. Core Data is available on both iOS and Mac OS, as is SQLite.

Comment: How would I control syncing between the 2 applications if I were to use SQLite or Core Data? Is there any easy way or do I have to keep track of new records on my own?

Comment: I don't have specific experience with this, but I think you should look into the Sync Services documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a document based application using CoreData.  This way you get a lot of features for free (file saving/loading, undo, etc). A bit of a steep learning curve if you are coming from iOS, but it's worth it.  Right now this template is only on the Mac, but if you are a registered developer, you can go look up a feature that they are adding in the fall that will help you. (I don't want the NDA police on SO complaining).

Comment: Thanks! I will consider it and check it out!